# Bounded subsequence in Sobolev Space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces

The following is an exercise.

Let $I=(0,1)$ and let $(u_n)$ be a bounded sequence in Sobolev space $W^{1,p}$,

> First question: does "bounded" here means that (for a suitable $M$)
>   $$
> \| u_n \|_p + \| u^\prime_n \|_p < M 
> $$
>   for all $x \in I$ and  all $n$ ?

I must prove that there exist a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ and some $u \in W^{1,p}$ such that $\| u_{n_k} - u \|_\infty$ goes to $0$.

> Second question: I know that there exist a subsequence $(u_{n_k})$ that goes to $u$, but this in $L^p$. Is it useful to use this information to prove the statement above? If not, how to get a bound on the expression $|u_{n_k}-u|$ ?

Comment: Q1: Roughly speaking, the answer is yes. Q2: the crucial point is existence of $L_p$ bound for the derivative. From $L_p$ bound you can get $L_1$ and then uniform continuity and uniform boundedness of $u_i.$ After that, Arzela- Ascoli will do the trick

Comment: I don't get why from derivatives that are in $L^1$ it follows uniform continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bf{\mbox{Answer to the first question}:}$ In general, when $(X,\|\|)$ is a normed space and $A\subset X$, we say that $A$ is bounded if there is $M>0$ such that $$\|a\|\le M,\ \forall a\in A$$

$\bf{\mbox{Answer to the second question}:}$ Here, the first thing you have to prove is that for $p\in (1,\infty]$, $W^{1,p}(0,1)$ is compactly embedded in $C(\overline{I})$. For a reference, see [Brezis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387709134) chapter 8.

If you have proved the first thing, now you are able to try and prove that if $u_n\to u$ weakly (in the weak topology) in $W^{1,p}(I)$ then, $u_n\to u$ strongly (in the norm topology) in $C(\overline{I})$.

Comment: There must be an easier way, I know this because my question is related to the proof of the fact that $W^{1,p}$ is a Banach space (see Brezis book, remark 4 and exercise 8.2). It is very likely to find the solution in Brezis' "Analyse fonctionnelle - Recueil de problemes et exercices" but I miss that book.

Comment: The word "easier" is relative. For me this proof is easy, in fact, it is a standard proof in the area of analysis. If you are plannig in study these things, you will see proofs like this plenty of times.

Comment: I did not mean to say that your proof was complex, of course. Thanks